# Lax-Friedrichs Scheme for second-order hyperbolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences, hyperbolic-equations

For the second-order hyperbolic PDE on $\Omega = (0,1)$:
$$ u_{tt}(x,t) = c^2 u_{xx}(x,t)\; , \quad \begin{cases}
    u(0,t) = L(t) \\
    u(1,t) = R(t) \\
    u(x,0) = f(x) \\
    u_t(x,0) = g(x)
\end{cases} $$
I would like to convert it into a first-order system and apply Lax-Friedrichs scheme. In particular, let
$$ r(x,t) = c u_x(x,t) \quad \text{and} \quad s(x,t) = u_t(x,t)$$
so that we have
$$ \begin{cases}
    r_t(x,t) = cs_x(x,t) \\
    s_t(x,t) = cr_x(x,t)
\end{cases} $$
By applying the Lax-Friedrichs scheme with $\{x_0, x_1, \cdots, x_J\}$ and $\{t^0, t^1, \cdots t^N\}$, we have
$$ \begin{cases}
    r^{n+1}_j = \frac{1}{2}\left( r^{n}_{j+1} + r^{n}_{j-1} \right) + \frac{c\Delta t}{2\Delta x} \left( s^{n}_{j+1} - s^{n}_{j-1} \right) \\
    s^{n+1}_j = \frac{1}{2}\left( s^{n}_{j+1} + s^{n}_{j-1} \right) + \frac{c\Delta t}{2\Delta x} \left( r^{n}_{j+1} - r^{n}_{j-1} \right) \\
    u^{n+1}_j = u^n_j + \Delta t \left(s^n_j\right)
\end{cases} $$

However, it looks like we need boundary and initial conditions for both $r$ and $s$ to solve this system. I know we have
$$ s^0_j = g(x_j) $$
How should I construct the remaining conditions for $r^0_j$, $r^n_0$, $r^n_J$, $s^n_0$ and $s^n_J$?

Answer (score 1):

The system of interest is

$$ \boldsymbol w_t + \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -c \\ -c & 0 \end{pmatrix} \boldsymbol w_x = \boldsymbol 0 \tag{1} \label{1}$$

with initial conditions

$$r(x,0) = c u_x(x, 0) = c \partial_x f(x), \quad s(x,0) = u_t(x, 0) = g(x). $$

---

The prescription of Dirichlet boundary conditions, i.e.,
$$u(0, t) = L(t), \quad u(1, t) = R(t) $$
is often not well-posed for hyperbolic systems.

The characteristic curves of the linearized system $\eqref{1}$ are
$$ x_\pm = x_0 \pm c t.$$

Consequently, the initial data is transported with speed $c$ to the left and right, respectively.
If the functions $L(t), R(t)$ are not constructed in a way such that the problem is well-posed, i.e., that $L(t), R(t)$ correspond to the initial data reaching the boundaries, there exists no solution and you simulation will produce meaningless results.

For general initial data (i.e., except for constant functions) I do not see how you would construct such $L(t), R(t)$, as there are multiple characteristic curves originating from different $x_0$ which reach the boundaries $0, 1$ at each time $t$.

If $r(x, 0) = c u_x = c f_x $ and $s(x, 0) = u_t(x, 0) = g(x)$ are both constant in $x$, however, you can use [d'Alemberts Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula) to compute the solution of the wave equation as

$$u(x, t) = g + ht = L(t) = R(t) $$ which is independent of space (as expected for initial data that does not depend on space) but still depends on time.

---

Something that should work, in contrast, are outflow boundary conditions $$r_0 = r_1, \: r_N = r_{N-1}, \quad s_0 = s_1, \: s_N = s_{N-1}$$
which are essentially Neumann boundary conditions that do not clash with the characteristics.